# Looping Observable Collection from the Last Item

Tags: c#, .net

```
foreach(var item in myObservalbleCollection)
{
    //samoe coding
}
```

Above code will loop the items in the observable class from the beginning. I want to loop the this object from the last Item

ex 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...
Please give me a solution to do this in c#

Comment: `foreach(var item in myObservalbleCollection.Reverse())`

Comment: Do you expect the collection to change while you are looping through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) the observablecollection and do the loop

```
var myObservalbleCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourType>(collection.Reverse());    
foreach(var item in myObservalbleCollection)
{
    //some coding
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `foreach` you can use a `for` loop running from the end of the collection and to the start:

```
for (var i = myObservableCollection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
  var item = myObservableCollection[i];
  // Process item
}
```

This is possible because `ObservableCollection<T>` implement `IList<T>` which provides both the count of the elements in the collection and indexed access to these elements in addition to the forward teration provided by `IEnumerable<T>` used by `foreach`. This is the most efficient solution.

You can also use LINQ `Reverse` which is available for any collection implementing `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
foreach (var item in myObservableCollection.Reverse()) {
  // Process item
}
```

This will actually copy all the elements in the collection to a new array before iterating them in reverse order. While less efficient than the first solution it should not matter in most cases.